# Reversing Sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, core-data

Does anyone know how to reverse the section order of a UITableView backed by an NSFetchedResultsController? I have two sections and basically just want to swamp them, yet still retain the order of the cells inside. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your sort descriptors array (I am assuming you have set the `sortDescriptors` property of your fetchRequest), you should have one array for section sort and one for content of section sort. If you have the section sort descriptor set to sort ascending, like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sectionSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"someKey" ascending:YES];
```

change it to

```
NSSortDescriptor *sectionSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"someKey" ascending:NO];
```

That should reverse the sort order of your sections.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jim. I actually only had one sortDescription because my sectionNameKeyPath is a method on a subclass of NSManagedObject. It's not possible to sort on a custom method such as this is it?